# Program crashes on line t->time = t0;

Tags: c, struct

I am usiung MinGW as my c programing environment, but I found a serious problem.
My test code is as follows:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {        /* time struct */
    time_t time;        /* time (s) expressed by standard time_t */
    double sec;         /* fraction of second under 1 s */
} gtime_t;

typedef struct {       
    gtime_t time;        
    int type;         
} raw_t;

int main(){
    raw_t *t;
    gtime_t t0={0};
    t->time = t0;
    printf ("%d",(t->time).time);

    return 0;
}
```

I defined two struct and one struct is contained in the other one. When I run this test program, it will crush on line

```
t->time = t0;
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: when copying a struct, a simple assignment will (usually) not do the job.  Suggest: `memcpy( &t->time, &to, sizeof( gtime_t ) );

Comment: the `double` format has an offset in the exponent, so initializing to {0} will not result in a value that is 0.0.  Suggest reading" <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format> which contains: "The double-precision binary floating-point exponent is encoded using an offset-binary representation, with the zero offset being 1023; also known as exponent bias in the IEEE 754 standard"

Answer (score 3):

t is a pointer that has not been initialized. So you can't dereferenced it to assign value to member. You can either initialize it by heap

```
t = malloc(sizeof(raw_t));
```

Or initialize by stack

```
raw_t tonthestack;
raw_t *t = &tonthestack;
```

Comment: [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses an uninitalized pointer:

```
raw_t *t;
t->time =
```

You must make `t` point somewhere before you are allowed to write `t->`.

A simpler solution would be to not use a pointer at all:

```
raw_t t = { 0 };
printf("%d\n", t.time.time);
```